# Where the correct place should i define a port of server( express )?

Tags: express, model-view-controller, port

I keep any hard coding information inside `models/config.js`, but i'm not sure that the `models/config.js` file is the correct place for a port.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a ./config/my_database_config.js  and put all there. 
Similar for ./config/main_server_config.js

usually all other config files can also go there.

You can hardcode values in this **my_database_config.js** file . Or this file could suppose make a request to the server for the config file that returns a following json. 
The config could be a json of type :

```
 configJson = {
 "env_production": {
     "db_host_production": "www.host.production.url",
     "db_password_production": "www.host.production.password"
 },

 "env_staging": {
     "db_host_staging": "www.host.staging.url",
     "db_password_staging": "www.host.staging.password"
 },
 "env_local": {
     "db_host_local": "www.host.local.url",
     "db_password_local": "www.host.local.password"
 }
}
```

If its is just for local testing puposes you could even pass in config values as env variables to the json in config.js